# Cancelling coroutine job after a certain amount of time

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

What I am trying to do is I am loading a webpage. If the pages takes too long to load I want to write a log message, if it loads in a predefined amount of time I want to cancel a job so that the log message does not get written

Here is what I have

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    loadTimer = launch {
        delay(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5))
        ensureActive()
        logUtil.w(TAG, "Loading took longer than expected")
    }

    webView.loadUrl(url)

}
```

Cancel when page is loaded

```
override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url)
    logUtil.i(TAG, "Finished loading $url")
    launch{
        loadTimer?.cancelAndJoin()
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that even after canceling, the log message still gets written. How can I cancel this properly so that it does not get written?

Comment: You mean "Loading took...." log gets written after "Finished loading" log? Also why do you use `cancelAndJoin` instead of just `cancel`?

Comment: Yes it is written after the Finished loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which CoroutineScope you're launching those coroutines from. Since they are called on implicit `this`, I suppose you created your own, or you made your Activity implement CoroutineScope directly? A lot of old tutorials showed that pattern, but it is obsolete now that Android Jetpack provides `lifecycleScope`, which is already set up to use `Dispatchers.Main`(`.immediate`) and cancels its jobs automatically in `onDestroy()`.

Anyway, I think **maybe** the problem is that you're cancelling your Job inside another launched coroutine. If your CoroutineScope is not using `Dispatchers.Main.immediate`, it will take a few ms until it makes the call to cancel. And since your initial Job was not on the main thread, there's a second race condition there. You don't need to use `cancelAndJoin()`, so you can eliminate the first race by calling `join()` synchronously.

Here's how to fix both of those race conditions:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    loadTimer = lifecycleScope.launch { // or with your current scope, use launch(Dispatchers.Main)
        delay(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5))
        logUtil.w(TAG, "Loading took longer than expected")
    }

    webView.loadUrl(url)
}
```

```
override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url)
    logUtil.i(TAG, "Finished loading $url")
    loadTimer?.cancel()
}
```

This theory would only give the two race conditions a window of a few ms where the page could load but the five second timer just runs out at almost the same time, so I'm not totally confident it is the issue.

Comment: I do create the coroutine by my fragment implementing CoroutineScope then using `SupervisorJob` to create the context `override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
 get() = Dispatchers.Main + job`

Comment: Any reason you don't use `lifecycleScope` or `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope`? Those are already set up to make your code leak-proof.

Comment: honestly its just older code, I will give it a try with lifecycleScope and report back

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to launch anything.  Just use [`withTimeout`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-timeout.html) to handle the cancellation and timeout correctly directly.

Comment: I dont see how I would be able to use withTimeout since I have to worry about two different methods for starting and knowing when its loaded